# Can't populate array with ListBox items

Tags: c#, asp.net, listbox, listitem

Here's a windows form I would like to use in a web form:

```
// Assign the people to groups.
private void btnAssign_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Get the names into an array.
    int numPeople = lstPeople.Items.Count;
    string[] names = new string[numPeople];
    lstPeople.Items.CopyTo(names, 0);

    // Randomize.
    Randomizer.Randomize<string>(names);

    // Divide the names into groups.
    int numGroups = int.Parse(txtNumGroups.Text);
    lstResult.Items.Clear();
    int groupNum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numPeople; i++)
    {
        lstResult.Items.Add(groupNum.ToString() +
            "    " + names[i]);
        groupNum = ++groupNum % numGroups;
    }
}
```

But the ListBox Asp.Net ListBox is not like the WinForms ListBox, so the line with:

```
lstPeople.Items.CopyTo(names, 0);
```

throws the following error:

> At least one element in the source array could not be cast down to the
>   destination array type.

I tried a lot, but can't find a way around. Please, help.

Comment: Why have you added the WPF tag here? I don't see any connection.

Answer (score 1):

In WebForms `ListBox` contains items of type `ListItem`, so at first an array should be declared differently:

```
ListItem[] names = new ListItem[numPeople];
lstPeople.Items.CopyTo(names, 0);
```

Also note that `names[i]` is no longer a string. Decide if you would like to use a Text or a Value, and change appropriately. E.g. for the `Text` (by the way you might want to use `string.Format` here):

```
 lstResult.Items.Add(groupNum.ToString() + "    " + names[i].Text);
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried ListItem, ListItemCollection and everything to complicate my life, but the answer was that easy. I also had to modify the `Randomizer` line from `<string>` to `<ListItem>` to make things work. No need to modify the `names[i]`, but it doesn't sort the groups together as it should.